# ONVIF wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl, onvif

I want to generate client code from onvif wsdl file, but I dont know where I can find wsdl files. I found something like this http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl, but it is html file, not wsdl. Does anyone know where I can find wsdl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That link is the wsdl file. Right click and view the source.

Comment: I got wsdl but when I try to parse it with wsimport it shows the following error: At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided. I use Java 1.7. Do you know what can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can import it as Service Reference - and when you make it, it will be available as regular namespace, with all its classes.